# how to create object 1 sliced by object 2?

Tags: modifiers, objects, boolean-modifier

In blender, if I create two intersecting objects A and B, I know how to obtain their intersections (A ⋂ B) or unions (A U B), or diff (A-B or B-A) using boolean modifiers.

However, I am wondering if there is a way for me to obtain A sliced by B (i.e. (A-B) U (A ⋂ B)), or likewise, B sliced by A, as a single output object? the result should contain both interior and exterior surfaces and should include multiple surface compartments.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

this geo nodes setup should work in your case. All I did was to make both boolean operations and join the results. Hope that helps
[image]